# How to mirror folders to a different hard drive?

Tags: windows, backup, mirroring

What I have:

- RAID 0 partition with 3 disks (A)
- a 500 gb disk (B)

What I want to do:

> Mirror folders from A to B

I want the backup folders to be fully accessible, so a backup program that compresses the files is not an option.

Is there a tool to do this for Windows?

Comment: Do you mean in real time or on a schedule?

Comment: How is it relevant that you have a RAID?

Comment: It isn't just wanted to share the setup. Otherwise someone would have said  I might be able to use raid 1 :>

Comment: @ Col realtime :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since someone has already given you an option for *nix I'll recommend one for windows, robocopy will do the job it's available for all versions of windows I think as a download from microsoft.

If you want a gui tool synctoy also from microsoft will do it.

Comment: This seems the easiest way, but how do I keep the mirror constantly the same ? I used robocopy /mir "H:\folder" "B:\folder" to backup that folder. Do I have to run the command everytime or is there away to add this to a crontab in windows ? Is there away to do this everytime a file is added to the H:\folder ? thanks :)

Comment: Just add it to the windows schedule, if you're using windows 7 just type schedule into the search box in the start menu. Otherwise it lurks in the control panel in Admin tools.  I don't think you can watch a folder for changes though.

Comment: After a bit more investigation I find that the /mon and /mot flags of robocopy allows you to monitor the folders and keep them in step. Theres and answer with more info here http://serverfault.com/questions/184677/windows-server-almost-real-time-directory-replication

Comment: Another question, any chance if there is a way like in unix you have '&' ? so that the cmd will run in the background ? thx!

Comment: If you kick it off from the scheduler there is a tickbox for hidden on windows 7 and server 2008 r2, what version of windows are we talking about.

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify your operating system. On *nix systems, rsync does just that - you can mirror one directory tree (or whole volume, which is usually just one directory tree, too) to another directory. The rsync program can be configured to look at either only the size, or size and checksum, and then it duplicates the structure.

If you so want, you can use rsync on Windows, too, by installing cygwin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807053/cygwin-rsync

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that, I am actually looking for rsync for windows :)